# comparing two lotteries

Tags: microeconomics, utility, risk-aversion, uncertainty

Suppose the prize space (in dollars) is $\mathbb{Z}$ = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8} and consider choices by an agent
whose preferences (over lotteries) satisfy the von Neumann-Morgenstern axioms.

A risk averse von Neumann-Morgenstern agent (with increasing utility) has to compare the
following two gambles

p = ($\frac{1}{8}$, $\frac{1}{8}$, $\frac{1}{8}$,$\frac{1}{8}$,$\frac{1}{8}$,$\frac{1}{8}$,$\frac{1}{8}$,$\frac{1}{8}$)

q=($\frac{2}{8}$,$0$, $\frac{1}{8}$,$\frac{1}{8}$,$\frac{1}{8}$,$\frac{1}{8}$,$0$,$\frac{2}{8}$)

Question is: Can you say unambiguously which one she would prefer?

I am thinking that if I can show one gamble second order stochastically dominates the other I can find the answer but I could not do that. Any help will be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with any of the definitions of risk aversion? How about applying one or the other?

Comment: Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Sure. Look up the definition in your textbook.

Comment: I looked up the definition but still it didn't help enough. I know a risk averse individual has concave utility function but I couldn't adapt it here.

Comment: The expected value is the same. What about variance? How is variance related to a risk-averse utility?

Comment: @user141240 variance of q is greater than variance of p hence q is riskier than p. So we can conclude that p has higher utility since agent is risk averse?